# How to measure rlogin time?

Tags: shell, shell-script, time, hp-ux

I need to monitor the time it takes to rlogin from one HP-UX machine to another.

So I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/sh
result=`rlogin 10.10.10.1 << EOF
exit
EOF`
result2=`{ time $result >/dev/null; } |& grep real`
echo $result2
```

This shellscript works when I run it on a Linux machine, but for some reason it doesn’t work when I run it on HP-UX. Both are using /bin/sh.

Why doesn't it work on HP-UX?

Comment: Why would one use an insecure protocol like `rlogin`?

Comment: I've never used `rlogin`, but this works with `ssh` and may work with `rlogin` too: `time ssh <host> true`

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `time` on the **output** of the rlogin command. That makes no sense.

`|&` is a bash feature. Probably your linux system has /bin/sh symlinked to bash, but most likely HP-UX does not.

You probably want:

```
#!/bin/sh
result=$( time rlogin 10.10.10.1 <<EOF 2>&1
exit
EOF
)
echo "$result" | grep real
```